# Warn about deprecated function during linking?

Tags: linker, solaris, ld

On Linux, you can easily tell the linker to emit a warning when the function is linked, e.g. like this:

```
static const char blah_msg[] __attribute__((section(".gnu.warning.blah"))) =
    "blah() is deprecated. Use blub().";
```

How to implement this warning behaviour on Solaris 10?

(i.e. with Solaris Studio and the Solaris `ld`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I asked the Solaris linker team, and there is no way to do this with the Solaris `ld` - using the compiler deprecated attribute is the closest you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37074/gjzke.html#indexterm-id-65):

> deprecated(msg)
>
> Results in a warning if the variable or function is used anywhere in the source file. The optional argument msg must be a string and will be included in the warning message if issued.

Comment: This does not answer the question. With the deprecated attribute, the warning comes from the compiler, i.e. it is emitted during compile time. It is not emitted at link time. Thus, the declaration in the header file must have this attribute set. In contrast to that: A linker warning is also emitted when someone uses a private function declaration (i.e. one that is missing any attributes).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
cc -V
```

Per this:

https://blogs.oracle.com/alanc/entry/solaris_11_2_functional_deprecation

The site wants 30 characters minimum - so here SO: I wrote something....sheesh

Comment: Does `cc -V` answer the question? The command `cc -V` prints the version of the compiler ... The linked article describes the `deprecated()` attribute (which was added to Solaris Studio 12.4) - that attribute was already posted by Andrew - and this also does not provide an answer to the question, as well.See my comment on Andrew's post for details.